# Good examples of websites that drive engagement for causes?

Tags: inspiration

I´m looking for good examples of websites for government, NGO´s and such that have clear and specific functions in their UI´s that make it easy to get involved and that drive engagement.

Example:  [Swedish Red Cross](http://www.redcross.se/stod-oss/fler-satt-att-stodja/ge-en-gava/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another wonderful example is the [Donors Choose](http://www.donorschoose.org/) site.

1) Clear call-to-action button for donors.
2) Seperate, prominent call-to-action for teachers.
3) Recent testimonials from other donors as encouragement.
4) Photos of the actual kids benefiting from various projects on the homepage.

Hope this helps. I annotated a screenshot, but too new to Stack Exchange to add it here.

Answer (score 4):

In my mind, while it's about micro-lending, you can still make the argument that [kiva.org](http://www.kiva.org/) is one of the most successful sites on the web at getting funds to those in need, to help themselves.

Answer (score 2):

my company recently did this

https://www.refunite.org/

Comment: Nice but what is the deal with the tiny search field?

Comment: dunno, that part was out of our control unfortunately, we wanted it bigger.

Answer (score 2):

While not cause-specific, there are probably some decent patterns to be found here: http://www.kickstarter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example pretty close to the others.

http://www.razoo.com/ (Donations and fundraising for nonprofits and charities online)